# Amazon-Redshift : Unload from pg_tables throwing error

Tags: amazon-redshift, catalog

I am trying to unload catalog pg_tables and pg_group and facing error. I am not able to figure out any fix:

1. pg_tables

```
unload ('SELECT schemaname||'''',
  tablename,
  tableowner,
  tablespace
FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables'
)
TO 's3://*********/*******/'
IAM_ROLE '******************'
PARQUET
ALLOWOVERWRITE

Warnings:
Function "pg_get_userbyid(integer)" not supported.

An error occurred when executing the SQL command:

[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.; [SQL State=0A000, DB Errorcode=500310]
1 statement failed.

Execution time: 1.52s
```

2. pg_group

```
unload ('SELECT
groname
,grosysid
,grolist
FROM pg_catalog.PG_GROUP'
)
TO 's3://*********/*********/'
IAM_ROLE '****************'
PARQUET
ALLOWOVERWRITE

Warnings:
Column "pg_group.grolist" has unsupported type "integer[]".

[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.; [SQL State=0A000, DB Errorcode=500310]
1 statement failed.

Execution time: 0.11s
```

I browsed through different websites and came to know that these are postgres specific datatype/functions which are not supported in redshift. Would be a great help if anyone can suggest a workaround for this.

Comment: Did you get any work around ?